# Chronometer inside AlertDialog

Tags: android

Just want to know if it is possible to make a chronometer appear inside of a AlertDialog?

```
AlertDialog.Builder popup = new AlertDialog.Builder(ScoreNewGame.this);
popup.setTitle("Timer");
```

What next though?
Kind regards

Comment: Yes that is possible. If you had googled this you would have found the answer by now... [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout) is a link to the official guide on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any View (including Chronometer) in a dialog with the [AlertDialog.Builder.setView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setView%28android.view.View%29) method.